# Getting error - javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Already connected while using POST request in Jersey

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

While using Jersey 2.x, I am trying to make a post request from a Java program acting as a client API.

This is my code:-

```
    Employee e = new Employee("John Doe",160);
    Response postResponse =  client.target("http://localhost:8081/employee/")
                            .path("createEmployee")
                            .request()
                            .post(Entity.json(e));
    if(postResponse.getStatus() != 201)
    {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
    Employee createdEmployee = postResponse.readEntity(Employee.class);
    System.out.println(createdEmployee);
```

While trying this code, I am getting an error:-

```
         javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Already connected
```

How the error can be solved?

Comment: Maybe, this exception is masked as mentioned here: https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues/3000.

Comment: but currently, I am using an HTTP request, how can it happen due to an SSL or TLS problem?